# Spring Webflux + Spring Security for X509 certificate validation issue: x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, x509certificate

I am facing an issue with Spring Security + Spring **Webflux** + X509 Client certificate validation.
May I get some assistance please?

With the minimal working code below:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class X509AuthenticationServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(X509AuthenticationServer.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public Mono<String> test() {
        return Mono.just("\n test \n");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity, UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, X509PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor) {
        return serverHttpSecurity.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated().and().x509().principalExtractor(principalExtractor).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public X509PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor() {
        return new SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService reactiveUserDetailsService) {
        return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(reactiveUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService mapReactiveUserDetailsService() {
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(User.withUsername("USER").authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")).password("").build());
    }

}
```

```
server.ssl.key-store=/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost
server.ssl.key-password=123456
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.trust-store=/truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=123456
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.port=8443
spring.security.user.name=test
spring.security.user.password=test

logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

I was expecting this to work, i.e. that I can do the X509 certificate validation.
However, I am facing this rather strange exception I am not understanding

```
2020-10-15 20:04:57.773 DEBUG [,9dfd3873894ac7fe,9dfd3873894ac7fe,true] 8646 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] .w.a.p.x.SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor : Subject DN is 'CN=(I see the correct CN), OU=zzzzzz, OU=xxxxxx, O=cccccc, C=US'
2020-10-15 20:04:57.773 DEBUG [,9dfd3873894ac7fe,9dfd3873894ac7fe,true] 8646 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] .w.a.p.x.SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor : Extracted Principal name is(I see the correct CN)
2020-10-15 20:04:57.785 DEBUG [,9dfd3873894ac7fe,9dfd3873894ac7fe,true] 8646 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [a8f68710/1-1] Resolved [ClassCastException: class sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')] for HTTP GET /test
2020-10-15 20:04:57.786 ERROR [,9dfd3873894ac7fe,9dfd3873894ac7fe,true] 8646 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [a8f68710/1-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/test

java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:99) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
```

Question: What does this "sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'" means, how did I end up with this issue, and how to fix it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager` is intended to validate a username/password not a X509 certificate, so it is trying to cast the X509 credential to a String to validate it like a password.

Instead, remove the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` Bean and allow the default `ReactivePreAuthenticatedAuthenticationManager` to be used which is automatically created from the `ReactiveUserDetailsService` bean. The `SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor` is the default, so there is no need to explicitly provide it, but if you need to customize it just expose it as a Bean and it will be used by default.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class X509AuthenticationServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(X509AuthenticationServer.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public Mono<String> test() {
        return Mono.just("\n test \n");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
            .x509();
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService mapReactiveUserDetailsService() {
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(User.withUsername("USER").authorities("USER").password("").build());
    }

}
```

You can also find a complete sample at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/592e4f89d2819f255340518a2c91b7e6eab6ed3e/reactive/webflux/java/authentication/x509/src/main/java/example/WebfluxX509Application.java

Comment: Hello @Rob, many thanks for this clear and detailed explanation. Upvoted. I was wondering, if I want to just add the actual check on the CN (like allowing only CNs containing a particular string) How to fit this into your example please?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/reactive-x509.html found it

Comment: Many thanks Rob for the clear explanation on the exception, and the steps to resolve it. Accepted